# mapping when using conditional statement

Tags: javascript, ejs

Hope someone can help,

On my site a user can log in and post a notice to the home page, they can then see all their notices and the user that posted the notice.

To show the notice author I am using the below map.

```
<% notices.map(notice => notice.author.username ) %>
<%= notice.author.username %>
```

Then I'm trying to say if there is no notice author (as in that user was deleted from the database) i want it to say "Author Unknown"

```
 <% if (!notice.author.username) { %>
     <p>Author Unknown</p>
 <% } else {%>
      <% notices.map(notice => notice.author.username ) %>
      <%= notice.author.username %>
 <% } %>
```

but the map seems to stop working in the conditional statement, any idea's???

Comment: Why have you tagged mongoose in this?

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
<%- notices.map(notice => notice.author.username ) %>
```

Instead,

```
<% notices.map(notice => notice.author.username ) %>
```

The Javascript functions should be wrapped around <%- %>

If that does not work then ,

Try using for loop or forEach.